# ArcPy to select by location not showing selected features in attribute table

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-addin

I have a button where it first calculate no of features in a specific layer and then runs the "are_identical_to" and update "D". After that it checks if the no of counts in two layers is same? If not, then runs the "are_identical_to" on two different layers and should show up the selected features in my data frame.

However it never shows the selected features in data frame or attribute table?

How can I achieve this.

code is shown below:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins


class Check1(object):
    """Implementation for Preproduction_Check_addin.Check1 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        lyr1 = ""
        lyr2 = ""
        lyr3 = ""
        result2 = ""
        result3 = ""
        count2 = ""
        count3 = ""
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
        for layer in layers:
            if layer.isFeatureLayer and layer.workspacePath != "":
                if "edits" in layer.name:
                    lyr1 = layer
                elif "fresh" in layer.name:
                    lyr2 = layer
                    result2 = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr2.dataSource)
                    count2 = int(result2.getOutput(0))
                    print("Total Features in fresh data:")
                    print(count2)
                elif "D" in layer.name:
                    lyr3 = layer

        Selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr1, "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", lyr2)
        if arcpy.Describe(lyr1.name).FIDSet:
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr1.name, "Update") as curs:
                for row in curs:
                    row = ("D",)
                    curs.updateRow(row)
                del curs
                del row
                print("Remark 'D' Updated")


        result3 = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr3.dataSource)
        count3 = int(result3.getOutput(0))


        print("Total features in 'D' Layer:")
        print(count3)

        if count3 == count2:
            print("Everything OK!, Please continue.")
        else:
            Selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr1, "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", lyr3,0,"SWITCH_SELECTION")
            print("Some features not matched, Please review.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` after applying the selection.

Comment: I also had to write the last selection statement in two lines as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33369771/11387707)